# How to extract year (or datetime) from a column in a pandas dataframe that contains text

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime, parsing

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe:

```
Id    Book                      
1     Harry Potter (1997)
2     Of Mice and Men (1937)
3     Babe Ruth Story, The (1948)   Drama   948)    Babe Ruth Story
```

How do I extract the year from the column?

Output should be:

```
Id    Book Title               Year
1     Harry Potter             1997
2     Of Mice and Men          1937
3     Babe Ruth Story, The     1948
```

So far I have tried:

```
movies['year'] = movies['title'].str.extract('([0-9(0-9)]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
```

and

```
books['year'] = books['title'].str[-5:-1]
```

I've messed around with some other things and haven't gotten it to work yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a simple Regex:

```
text = 'Harry Potter (1997)'
re.findall('\((\d{4})\)', text)
# ['1997'] Note that this is a list of "all" the occurrences.
```

---

With a Dataframe, it can be done like this:

```
text = 'Harry Potter (1997)'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Book': text}, index=[1])
pattern = '\((\d{4})\)'
df['year'] = df.Book.str.extract(pattern, expand=False) #False returns a series

df
#                  Book   year
# 1  Harry Potter (1997)  1997
```

---

Finally, if you actually want to separate the title and the data (taking the dataframe reconstruction from Philip in another answer):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Book'], data=[['Harry Potter (1997)'],['Of Mice and Men (1937)'],['Babe Ruth Story, The (1948)   Drama   948)    Babe Ruth Story']])

sep = df['Book'].str.extract('(.*)\((\d{4})\)', expand=False)

sep # A new df, separated into title and year
#                       0      1                           
# 0          Harry Potter   1997 
# 1       Of Mice and Men   1937
# 2  Babe Ruth Story, The   1948
```

Comment: Nice! This is pretty much what I was looking for. If I do this I would have to use a for loop through all the values in the pandas series, which is extremely slow. This helped me get the correct answer, which is this:

books['title'].str.findall('\((\d{4})\)').str.get(0)

Comment: Whoops I mean df['Books']. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @MattElgazar See my last update to extract the title as well =) Thanks for the fun problem; I learned a few things figuring this out

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','Book'], data=[[1,'Harry Potter (1997)'],[2,'Of Mice and Men (1937)'],[3,'Babe Ruth Story, The (1948)   Drama   948)    Babe Ruth Story']])

df['Year'] = df['Book'].str.extract(r'(?!\()\b(\d+){1}')
```

1. line: import pandas
2. line: create the dataframe for sake of understanding
3. line: create a new column 'Year', which is created from a string extraction on the column Book.

Use regex to find the digits. I use https://regex101.com/r/Bid0qA/1, which is a huge help in understanding how regex works.

Comment: This actually works for the cases I have presented but it does not work for all cases. See this example.

Some Book Title 2 (2002)

Comment: Ahh well I was about to write you. That it did work. Post more data so that we have more to work with. If you add more cases along the way you are making it a lot harder to actually answer the question. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the full series is actually this:

```
books['title'].str.findall('\((\d{4})\)').str.get(0)
```